# Unity IsPointerOverGameObject Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know it's a common problem but none worked. Maybe the button setup is wrong. I have a Panel with no image, and inside a settings button on the top left that once clicked opens another scene. I tried using those 3 methods but none works. It always detects it as a Game object.

The bool `isGameStarted` is checking if the player should move or no.
Please guide me through

Have tried

```
if (Swipe.Instance.Tap && !isGameStarted)
{
    if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() )
    { 
        isGameStarted = false;
    }
    else
    {
          isGameStarted = true;
          motor.StartRunning();
          gameCanvas.SetTrigger("Show");
    }
}
```

Also tried using trigger but it goes through the UI.

This is the original code.

```
if (Swipe.Instance.Tap && !isGameStarted)
{ 
    isGameStarted = true;
    motor.StartRunning();
    gameCanvas.SetTrigger("Show");
}
```

Once you tap on the screen the player starts moving. I need it NOT to move or start the game if clicked on the settings button.

Comment: does your button in general react to a hover or click?

Comment: Yes, my button works as needed. The issue is when I press the button, the game starts(character moves) + open the other scene(as supposed to do).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem until I figured out that IsPointerOverGameObject seems to return true for any GameObject (possibly with a collider) and not only UI objects.

So I wrote a custom static class to check for UI objects only. You will need to set the layer of each panel, image, button, etc. to UI for it to work.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public static class MouseOverUILayerObject
{
    public static bool IsPointerOverUIObject()
    {
        PointerEventData eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        eventDataCurrentPosition.position = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);

        for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
        {
            if (results[i].gameObject.layer == 5) //5 = UI layer
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
      if (!MouseOverUILayerObject.IsPointerOverUIObject())
            HandleClick();
}
```

Comment: Spent hours on this.. Finally your method worked!!

Answer (score 1):

The overload of [`IsPointerOverGameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html) takes a parameter

> `int pointerId`  Pointer (touch / mouse) ID.

and

> If you use `IsPointerOverGameObject()` without a parameter, it points to the "left mouse button" (pointerId = `-1`);
>
> therefore when you use `IsPointerOverGameObject` **for touch, you should consider passing a pointerId to it.**

So from the example

```
if (Swipe.Instance.Tap && !isGameStarted)
{
    if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId))
    { 
        isGameStarted = false;
        return;
    }
    
    isGameStarted = true;
    motor.StartRunning();
    gameCanvas.SetTrigger("Show");
}
```

otherwise if you have multiple possible touches you could also do the check for all of them like

```
if (Swipe.Instance.Tap && !isGameStarted)
{
    foreach(var touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
        { 
            isGameStarted = false;
            return;
        }
    }
    
    isGameStarted = true;
    motor.StartRunning();
    gameCanvas.SetTrigger("Show");
}
```

---

also look at [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ispointerovereventsystemobject-always-returns-false-on-mobile.265372/)